# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable (Content Spinner)

Tags: python

I'm trying to use [this spinner](https://github.com/screename/Spinner) to re-write strings.

when I try to run the same exact code as in the readme:

bot.py:

```
108: from spinner import spinner
109: s = spinner()
110: spintax = s.getSpintax('Everything in moderation, including moderation.')
111: spun = s.spin(spintax)
112: print spintax, spun
```

When I do so, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Reddit\bot.py", line 110, in <module>
    spintax = s.getSpintax('Everything in moderation, including moderation.')
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Reddit\spinner.py", line 56, in getSpintax
    n, syn = self.getSynonyms(stem)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Reddit\spinner.py", line 36, in getSynonyms
    for lemma in syn.lemmas:
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

the relevant code for that error message is:

spinner.py:

```
   32: def getSynonyms(self, word):
   33:   # include the original word
   34:     synonyms = [word]
   35:     for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
   36:         for lemma in syn.lemmas:
   37:             if lemma.name != word:
   38:              # since wordnet lemma.name will include _ for spaces, we'll replace these with spaces
   39:                 w, n = re.subn("_", " ", lemma.name)
   40:                 synonyms.append(w)
   41:     s = list(set(synonyms))
   42:     return len(s), s
   43: 
   44: # transform text into spintax with the folowing steps
   45: # 1. split the text to sentences
   46: # 2. loop through the sentences and tokenize it
   47: # 3. loop thorugh each token, find its stem and assemble all the synonyms of it into the spintax
   48: def getSpintax(self, text):
   49:     sentences = self.splitToSentences(text)
   50:     stemmer = PorterStemmer()
   51:     spintax = ""
   52:     for sentence in sentences:
   53:         tokens = regexp_tokenize(sentence, "[\w']+")
   54:         for token in tokens:
   55:             stem = stemmer.stem(token)
   56:             n, syn = self.getSynonyms(stem)
   57:             spintax += "{"
   58:             spintax += token
   59:             spintax += "|"
   60:             for x in range(n):
   61:                 spintax += syn[x]
   62:                 if x < n-1:
   63:                     spintax += "|"
   64:                 else:
   65:                     spintax += "} "
   66:     return spintax
```

I've tried both in Python 3 and 2

I'm not familiar with spinner.py since I just grabbed it from the internet, I just need something that will spin text for me for free. Also, what does the following line do:

```
synonyms = [word]
```

if anyone can recommend some other free text spinner I can use i'd be willing to try something else, but I tried a bunch and this one was the most straightforward, I just want to pass in a line of text, or file, and have it re-written based on synonyms/etc. This seems like the best option I have for doing that, I just don't really know what's going wrong with the code.

Comment: Try: `for lemma in syn.lemmas()` -- note the parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hai-vu is right. You need to change the getSynonyms function to:

```
#     get all synonyms of a word from the wordnet database
    def getSynonyms(self, word):
#         include the original word
        synonyms = [word]
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
            for lemma in syn.lemmas():
                if lemma.name() != word:
#                     since wordnet lemma.name will include _ for spaces, we'll replace these with spaces
                    w, n = re.subn("_", " ", lemma.name())
                    synonyms.append(w)
        s = list(set(synonyms))
        return len(s), s
```

Comment: this worked, I appreciate the help. 

Can you tell me what the "synonyms = [word]" line is doing? I'm not really sure how to look that up, is it like casting the "word" variable as a list or something?

Comment: it creates synonyms as a list. And puts the content of word in that list.